# PyQt5 Error conexion a Mysql "Driver not loaded"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, mysqlconnector

No consigó solucionar este error que me aparece al intentar conectarme a una base de datos Mysql con PyQt5

Instruccion utilizada:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys


def dbcon():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName('localhost')
    db.setDatabaseName('db_librowad')
    db.setUserName('root')
    db.setPassword('12345')
    ok = db.open()
    if not ok: print(db.lastError().text())
    # else: print("connected")
    query = QSqlQuery(db)
    query.exec_('SELECT * FROM tbl_Customers')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dbcon()
```

Mensaje de Error

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109326/error-driver-not-loaded-in-pyqt5  Respuesta a una pregunta similar.

Comment: ya provaste intentado bajar el driver correcto [drivers mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/)

Comment: @Bryro, encontre la solucion, descargando esta dll ( libmysql.dll ), e incluyendo en la misma ubicación de mi archivo py

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontre fue simple, descargando el archivo dll,  de este link [libmysql](https://github.com/weldermarcosxd/pyqt5-mysql) y ubicando en la misma carpeta donde tengo este archivo .py de conexion a la base de datos MYSQL.
Obs. El Sistema operativo que utilizó es W7.